# Gzip filter with Spring async

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

I am using the new Servlet 3 feature `DefferedResult` in my Spring-MVC application. I had a GZIP filter which I had to remove as `DefferedResult` did not work with it.

Can someone tell me if there is a GZipFilter that will work with the Spring async(DefferedResult)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the filter introduced in servlet 3 -  asyncSupported

```
@WebFilter(servletNames = { "servletAsynFilter" }, asyncSupported=true)  
public class Filter1 implements Filter {  
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {}  
    public void destroy() {}  

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {  

        HttpServletResponseWrapper respWrap = new HttpServletResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse)response);  
        chain.doFilter(request, respWrap);  

    }  
}
```